# Can i reference an exe in a class library?

Tags: c#

Can i reference an exe in the class library which in turn is used by excel. I have referenced the project reference in class library(dll). My exe will run whenever i open excel or if it is running it will point to it as it is singleton. while exe is running some of the global values will change.but whenever i am using some function of dll from the excel , it is not using changed values instead it is using unchanged values. How do i see that every exe will point to same exe and values are from it.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean - do you mean if you can Add Reference to EXE file rather than to DLL file?

Comment: no, i have added a project reference of an exe in a dll and using some of the methods of exe. the final dll is used by excel. My problem is i want to use some of the values of exe which are changed while runnning. i.e. it is getting some values from services, these values to be used. But what am i seeing is unchanged initialised values rather the values from the services.

Comment: So I fear your only choice is interprocess communication, as suggested by Mat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are saying that the exe which is running in a seperate process to the dll, cannot share it's globals with the dll?

You are going to have to look at other methods of interprocess communication. In .NET the first method that springs to mind is using [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx). I don't think there is any way to do what you want easily.