# How do i communicate between a dll and an exe?

Tags: c#

i have a dll which has to get some values from the running exe. So Can i do this by WCF? i.e whenever request is sent from dll to the service that in turn should request running exe and give the result.The dll which i am referring is a COM dll used in EXcel. Can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i reference an exe in a class library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880327/can-i-reference-an-exe-in-a-class-library)

Comment: WCF is definitely and option and sticking with REST you can easily send values back and forth in clear text using xml or json formatting.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the above question @Henk, But around that question. I need WCF as common contact between exe and dll.

Comment: it probably won't get 5 close votes. But this is your second attempt and still the essential info (COM) has to be squeezed out of you.

Answer (score 1):

A .dll is not an application by it self. It should be included in you application(.exe).
Here is a link of how to use a .dll : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for giving me -1 without any comment on my response

Comment: no , i have not given -1 . if i reference the dll in exe , it will be separate instance i think. This dll i am using as COM dll referenced in Excel which internally calls methods from this dll.

Comment: @Ershad please add this information to your question to make it more clearly. When i first read the question i understood that the dll is loaded by the same app that it wanted to collect data from. And that why i posted that answer.

Comment: there is some right in your answer. i give +1 on your post ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WCF is perfectly capable of doing this. But you have to add some code to the running executable as well. I assume that's possible?

[Here's a 'Getting Started' tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) from Microsoft.

**Edit: ** As Gabriel points out, I assume that the DLL is already used by another executable or website.

Comment: i have seen the tutorial like i have to have the methods in service contract and these can be called from anywhere. But how do internally call the exe's methods inside the service.

Comment: You have to be a little more clear about this. I can't tell you because I don't know the structure of the application.

Comment: I have one COMdll which is used in Excel.whenever some method of this dll is called from the excel i have to take some dynamic values from exe or i have to run some of the methods of exe which is running. So i thought i will keep WCF as intermediate and do the requirement. But before start i need to know is it possible?

Comment: So the COMdll (written in .NET?) will call the executable? If the COMdll is written in .NET, it is possible. The DLL only needs to know where the WCF service is running (Address) and which interface the service implements (Contract).

Comment: yes, COMdll is in .NET. But how WCF communicate with exe's methods?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/12/15/create-and-consume-wcf-service-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx . Your dll is the client whereas the exe will be the service.